# Diameter Protocol End-to-End identifier

Tags: diameter-protocol

In case of retry can the Diameter message have the same End-to-End identifier value as the original Diameter message initially sent.

Seems RFC 3588 doesn't clearly say about this particular scenario

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

It does say.
One example from the RFC(section 5.5.4):

> It is important to note that multiple identical requests or answers
>      MAY be received as a result of a failover.  The End-to-End Identifier
>      field in the Diameter header along with the Origin-Host AVP MUST be
>      used to identify duplicate messages.